# Hyperledger Composer with hlfv14

Tags: putty, composer

I'm having issues on deploying hyperledger composer@0.20 with hlfv14 multi org, multi-nodes setup.

My putty screen disappeared when entering this Composer command. Keys are in place.

`$composer card create -p org1onlyconnection.json -u PeerAdmin -c "${CERT}" -k "${PRIVATE_KEY}" -r PeerAdmin -r ChannelAdmin --file /tmp/PeerAdmin@org1-only.card`

Comment: I edited you formatting.  Try to edit your question to explain more clearly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I Found a solution, it's due to the json file format, this will useful if anyone faces the same issue.
Note:  There are few json Schema errors over peers and organization section ( extra parenthesis and Comma(,) missing. I was able to create a card and import now.
I used this online tool: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net for checking.

{**strong text**
    "name": "pocnet1-org1-only",
    "x-type": "hlfv1",
    "x-commitTimeout": 300,**strong text**
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "Org1",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300",
                    "eventHub": "300",
                    "eventReg": "300"
                },
                "orderer": "300"
            }
        }
    },
    "channels": {
        "composerchannel": {
            "orderers": [
                "orderer.example.com"
            ],
            "peers": {
                "peer0.org1.example.com": {},
                "peer1.org1.example.com": {},
                "peer2.org1.example.com": {}
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Org1": {
            "mspid": "Org1MSP",
            "peers": [
                "peer0.org1.example.com",
                "peer1.org1.example.com",
                "peer2.org1.example.com"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.org1.example.com"
            ]
        }
    },
    "orderers": {
        "orderer.example.com": {
            "url": "grpc://localhost:7050"
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpc://localhost:7051",
            "eventUrl": "grpc://localhost:7053"
        },
        "peer1.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpc://localhost:8051",
            "eventUrl": "grpc://localhost:8053"
        },
        "peer1.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpc://localhost:9051",
            "eventUrl": "grpc://localhost:9053"
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "http://localhost:7054",
            "caName": "ca.org1.example.com"
        }
    }
}

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/888633)

Comment: It's great you found the solution to your problem, thank you for completing the loop. However, it's not entirely clear how you solved your problem. Could you [edit] your answer and explain what you did and how json file format related to that? Cheers!

Comment: @RajeshS, Yes it was a clueless issue since the putty connection getting disappeared and no errors on docker services.